# api Telegram webhook : how can delete new_chat_participant message

Tags: telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I created a bot via `webhook` method of api telegram and It's okay and working.

but I want know how can delete any `new_chat_participant` messages before sending message by members.

You know that telegram don't send request to your hook url until have not any message with members !!!!!!!

I need just message_id for example when a member add an another to supper group.

[image]

Comment: @JJohnson when you can't understand why you do replay?? my question is very clear! I want delete mentions information for example when you add a new member to group telegram automate send mention info in group chat. so I want delete very fast that message.

Comment: @JJohnson please make sure before answer. I checked more bot that can delete it very fast you can check  (http://t.me/Z_linksbot)  bot haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `/setprivacy` to disable in @BotFather to receive the whole actions and messages from your group. (In order to delete these messages, the bot must has access to messages in the group, needs to be administrator).

When new member has been added to group, you will receive a json in your webhook something like this:

```
{ update_id: 123123123,
  message:
    { message_id: 2599,         // Pay attention to this message id
      from: {
        ...
      },
      chat: {
        id: -987372183          // This is your group's id
        ...
      },
      date: 1582378239,
      new_chat_participant: {        // Field when new member is added to group

      }
      ...
}
```

Now you need to send a post request to Telegram to delete this message (action). The request is:

request.post("https://api.telegram.org/botYOUR_BOT_TOKEN/deleteMessage?chat_id=GROUP_ID&message_id=MESSAGE_ID_RECEIVED", ... )

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know whole you explan. but main problem is when you using of webhook you got error : `can't use getUpdates method while webhook is active` and when using `webhook` you will not receive request. when telegram server send you request hook posts that a of member send a message to group chat

Comment: You will receive these actions in your webhook, I have a bot implemented on multiple groups and I have disabled `/setprivacy` (this is really important to receive all actions and messages of any kind). Do you have this option disabled on @BotFather?

Comment: yes its right, my error was of `['message']['text']` this request hadn't text value and also my webhook get error. I fixed that. thank you